# Quotation Marks around inserted text in echo

Tags: php

I think this can be simply solved. I'm just not sure how to do it.
This is my code right now:

```
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded here: " . "<a href='$file'>$file</a>" ;
```

This outputs

> The file whatever.jpg has been uploaded...

What I would like to achieve is:

> The file "whatever.jpg" has been uploaded...

Notice the quotes. Sorry if this is incredibly easy to do, I'm kind of new.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Use single quotes for encapsulation and just put the doubles in; or escape the double quotes in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when I have a text not too long with some variables inside, to avoid closing and opening quotes and intercalating concatenations I prefer to use printf:

```
printf('The file "%s" has been uploaded here: <a href="%s">%s</a>', 
       basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]), 
       $file, 
       $file);
```

This is much cleaner to me and helps to avoid mistakes, specially when there are function calls and arrays.

Comment: Thank you, Worked perfectly without problems. I was considering using it but I stuck with echo which i was using throughout my website.

Comment: don't get tied to anything, just use was gives you the desired result, PHP has a function for every need! Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to just swap out the quotation marks with single quotes like...

```
echo 'The file "' . basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]) . '" has been uploaded here: ' . '<a href="$file">$file</a>';
```

Comment: Works fine just the $file in the anchor tag displays as $file and not what I have defined as $file ($uploadDir . time() . '_' . rand(100, 999) . '.' . end($explode);)

Answer (score 0):

Single quotation mark:

```
echo 'The file "' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) . '"' . ' has been uploaded here: ' . ' < a href=>$file </a > ';
```

Comment: Works fine just the $file in the anchor tag displays as $file and not what I have defined as $file ($uploadDir . time() . '_' . rand(100, 999) . '.' . end($explode);)